# Stream Tweets asynchronously with Tweepy AsyncStream

Tags: python, asynchronous, twitter, python-asyncio, tweepy

I'm trying to run AsyncStream Tweepy, but I ran into a problem

My code

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, print_function
from tweepy.streaming import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream
from pprint import pprint
from tweepy.asynchronous import AsyncStream 
import asyncio

async def main():

    stream = StdOutListener(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
    await stream.filter(follow=['1082189695252074496'])
    await asyncio.sleep(1.5)


class StdOutListener(AsyncStream):
    
    
    async def on_status(self, status):
        print(status_json)

    async def on_error(self, status):
        print(status)
            
if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

When I run it in .py file, it doesn't work and returns the error "An HTTP: 420 error occurred in the stream".
I also run the code in Jupyter Notebook, only instead of async io.run(main ()), I write await main(), it also returns this error, BUT the stream works and it returns a response.

Why does it work in Jupyter Notebook, but does not work in the .py file. How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

According to the Tweepy documentation section on [Handling Errors](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/streaming_how_to.html#handling-errors):

> If clients exceed a limited number of attempts to connect to the streaming API in a window of time, they will receive error 420. The amount of time a client has to wait after receiving error 420 will increase exponentially each time they make a failed attempt.
>
> Tweepy’s Stream Listener passes error codes to an on_error stub. The default implementation returns False for all codes, but we can override it to allow Tweepy to reconnect for some or all codes...

Here's another reference to the Twitter API documentation section on [HTTP Error Codes](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/filter-realtime/guides/connecting#errorcodes).

1. The first isssue is that `print(status_json)` should be `print(status._json)`.
2. The second issue is that the `on_status` method needs to conditionally return True or False based on `status._json`, like so:

   ```py
   async def on_status(self, status):
       if hasattr(status, "_json"):
           print(status._json)
           # returning non-False continues the stream
           return True
       else:
           # returning False disconnects the stream
           return False
   ```
3. The third issue is that the `on_error` method needs to conditionally return True or False based on the value of `status`, like so:

   ```py
   async def on_error(self, status):
       if status == 420:
           # returning False disconnects the stream
           return False
       else:
           # returning non-False continues the stream
           return True
   ```